# Can ImageResizer be exploited if presets are not enabled?

Tags: imageresizer

My project uses the Presets plugin with the flag onlyAllowPresets=true.

The reason for this is to close a potential vulnerability where a script might request an image thousands of times, resizing with 1px increment or something like that.

My question is: Is this a real vulnerability? Or does ImageResizer have some kind of protection built-in?

I kind of want to set the onlyAllowPresets to false, because it's a pain in the butt to deal with all the presets in such a large project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only know of one instance where this kind of attack was performed. If you're that valuable of a target, I'd suggest using a firewall (or CloudFlare) that offers DDOS protection.

An attack that targets cache-misses can certainly eat a lot of CPU, but it doesn't cause paging and destroy your disk queue length (bitmaps are locked to physical ram in the default pipeline). Cached images are still typically served with a reasonable response time, so impact is usually limited.

That said, run a test, fake an attack, and see what happens under your network/storage/cpu conditions. We're always looking to improve attack handling, so feedback from more environments is great.

Most applications or CMSes will have multiple endpoints that are storage or CPU-intensive (often a wildcard search). Not to say that this is good - it's not - but the most cost-effective layer to handle this often at the firewall or CDN.  And today, most CMSes include some (often poor) form of dynamic image processing, so remember to test or disable that as well.

### Request signing

If your image URLs are originating from server-side code, then there's a clean solution: sign the urls before spitting them out, and validate during the `Config.Current.Pipeline.Rewrite event`.  We'd planned to have a plugin for this shipping in v4, but it was delayed - and we've only had ~3 requests for the functionality in the last 5 years.

The sketch for signing would be:

1. Sort querystring by key
2. Concatenate path and pairs
3. HMACSHA256 the result with a secret key
4. Append to end of querystring.

For verification:

1. Parse the query,
2. Remove the hmac
3. Sort query and concatenate path as before
4. HMACSHA256 the result and compare to the value we removed.
5. Raise an exception if it's wrong.

Our planned implementation would permit for 'whitelisted' variations - certain values that a signature would permit to be modified by the client - say for breakpoint-based width values. This would be done by replacing targeted key/value pairs with a serialized whitelist policy prior to signature. For validation, pairs targeted by a policy would be removed prior to signature verification, and policy enforcement would happen if the signature was otherwise a match.

Perhaps you could add more detail about your workflow and what is possible?

Comment: Thank you for a detailed response! I'm not too knowledgeable about the infrastructure part of the project, I'm more of a frontend dev, but I will take your answer with me to the team. I reckon it's safe to turn off the onlyAllowPresets flag.